I've tried everything in the book and I still can't fix "Exception has occurred" (HiveError: The box "tasks" is already open and of type Box<Task>.)
I'm getting an error

HiveError: The box "tasks" is already open and of type Box

in my TaskClassFunctions file, even thought I never use .openbox again and use <type> correctly.
So yeah I don't know what to do.
Here's my code - this is my main:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';
import 'Pages/_home.dart';
import 'Pages/_files.dart';
import 'Pages/_notes.dart';
import 'Pages/_settings.dart';
import 'Pages/_tasks.dart';
import 'pages/TasksClass.dart';  

void main() async {

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  // Step 1: Initialize Hive
  await Hive.initFlutter(); // Initialize Hive
  Hive.registerAdapter(TaskAdapter()); // Register the Task model

  await Hive.openBox<Task>('tasks'); // Open a Hive box for tasks

  // Step 2: Run the app
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Step 3: MaterialApp setup with routes
    return MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => Home(),
        '/Files': (context) => Files(),
        '/Notes': (context) => Notes(),
        '/Settings': (context) => Settings(),
        '/Tasks': (context) => Tasks(),
      },
    );
  }
}

My home
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_arc_text/flutter_arc_text.dart';
import 'dart:math';
import 'TasksClassFunctions.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

      //The Appbar is almost the same for all pages
      appBar: AppBar(

        backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 128, 135, 171),//Same Color for all Pages
        title: const Text(
          'AppTitle',
          style: TextStyle(//Same Title Style for all pages
            fontSize:40,
            color: Color.fromARGB(255, 163, 13, 13),//Same Color for all Pages
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
            fontFamily: 'School',

          ),
          
          ),
        centerTitle: true,

        actions: [
          SettingsButton()
        ],

    ),

    //Using Column as my main composition, and container to keep the gradient background
    body: Container(
      
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(//Same Gradient For All Pages
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.topCenter,
            end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            colors: [Color.fromARGB(255, 45, 91, 91),Color.fromARGB(255, 102, 204, 204)]

          ),

        ),
        
        child:Column(

          children: [

            const Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              child: Text(
              
                'Welcome Back',
              
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize:40,
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                  fontFamily: 'School',
                ),
              ),
            ),

            const SizedBox(height: 30,),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: TakePhotoButton(imagePath: 'Assets/CameraLens.png', text: "Take a Photo",)
              ),
            
            const SizedBox(height: 30),

            TaskList(),
          ],
        )
       
    ),
    );
  }
}


class SettingsButton extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<SettingsButton> createState() => _SettingsButtonState();
}

class _SettingsButtonState extends State<SettingsButton> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
     
      onPressed: (){
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/Settings');//Should send me directly to the Settings page, check routes on main
      }, icon: const Icon(Icons.settings)//Simple Settings Icon
      );
  }
}


class TakePhotoButton extends StatefulWidget {
  final String imagePath;  // Path to your image
  final String text;       // Text surrounding the circumference

  TakePhotoButton({required this.imagePath, required this.text});

  @override
  State<TakePhotoButton> createState() => _TakePhotoButtonState();
}

class _TakePhotoButtonState extends State<TakePhotoButton> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        // Action on button press
        print("PhotoTaken");
      },
      child: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        children: [
          // Circular container with image
          Container(
            height: 120,  // Button height
            width: 120,   // Button width (same value for perfect circle)
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              shape: BoxShape.circle,  // Make it circular
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage(widget.imagePath),  // Use your image here
                fit: BoxFit.cover,  // Cover the container
              ),
            ),
          ),
          // Circular text surrounding the button
          Positioned(
            bottom: 60,  // Adjust text position if needed
              child: ArcText(
              radius: 60, // Radius of the text arc
              text: widget.text,
              textStyle: const TextStyle(
                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 20,
              ),
              startAngle: -pi / 2, // Starts at the top (12 o'clock position)
              stretchAngle: pi, // Spans 180 degrees (half-circle)
              startAngleAlignment: StartAngleAlignment.start, // Aligns text starting from startAngle
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

And finally my TaskClass and TaskClass functions
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';

part 'TasksClass.g.dart';

//Class that represents tasks, saved in Hive
@HiveType(typeId: 0) // Unique typeId for each model
class Task extends HiveObject {
  @HiveField(0)
  String title;

  @HiveField(1)
  DateTime dueDate;

  Task({required this.title, required this.dueDate});
}


import 'TasksClass.dart';  
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';


//To create a Task Manually
class ManualTaskInput extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ManualTaskInputState createState() => _ManualTaskInputState();
}

class _ManualTaskInputState extends State<ManualTaskInput> {

  //This is so that the user can type 
  final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController(); 
  DateTime? _selectedDate;

  @override
  //Get rid of the text controller, good practice to avoid memory leaks
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  // Function to show date picker and set the selected date
  Future<void> _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
    final DateTime? picked = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: DateTime.now(),
      firstDate: DateTime.now(),
      lastDate: DateTime(2050),
    );
    if (picked != null && picked != _selectedDate){
      setState(() {
        _selectedDate = picked; // Store the selected date
      });
    }
  }

  void NewTask() async {
    final inputText = _controller.text;
    if (inputText.isNotEmpty && _selectedDate != null) {
      //final box = await Hive.openBox<Task>('tasks'); // Open the tasks box , but not sure if I needit since I open at the main
        final box=Hive.box('tasks');

      final newTask = Task(
        title: inputText,
        dueDate: _selectedDate!,  // Use the selected due date
      );

      await box.add(newTask);  // Add the task to the box
      print('Task added: $inputText with due date: $_selectedDate');
    } else {
      print('No input or due date provided.');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        TextField(
          controller: _controller,
          decoration: const InputDecoration(
            labelText: 'Enter a new Task:',
            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 16),
         ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () => _selectDate(context), // Trigger date picker
          child: Text(_selectedDate == null
              ? 'Select Due Date'
              : 'Selected Date: ${_selectedDate!.toLocal()}'.split(' ')[0]), // Display selected date
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 16),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: NewTask,
          child: Text('Create Task'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}


//Reable function fo the child select date

/*String getDueDateText(DateTime? selectedDate) {
  if (selectedDate == null) {
    return 'Select Due Date'; // Default text when no date is selected
  } else {
    // Format the selected date (only display YYYY-MM-DD)
    return 'Selected Date: ${selectedDate.toLocal()}'.split(' ')[0];
  }
}*/


//Show The Tasks
class TaskList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TaskListState createState() => _TaskListState();
}

class _TaskListState extends State<TaskList>{

  get taskbox => Hive.box<Task>('tasks');

  // Format the due date to show 'Today' or 'Tomorrow'
  String formatDueDate(DateTime dueDate) {
    final now = DateTime.now();
    final today = DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day);
    final tomorrow = today.add(Duration(days: 1));
    

    if (dueDate.isAtSameMomentAs(today)) {
      return "Today";
    } else if (dueDate.isAtSameMomentAs(tomorrow)) {
      return "Tomorrow";
    }else if (dueDate.isBefore(today)){
      return "Due";
    } else {
      return "${dueDate.toLocal()}".split(' ')[0]; // Standard date format (yyyy-mm-dd)
    }
  }

  // Delete task with confirmation
  void _deleteTask(int index) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
        title: const Text("Delete Task"),
        content: const Text("Are you sure you want to delete this task?"),
        actions: [
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(), // Cancel
            child: const Text("Cancel"),
          ),
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              taskbox.deleteAt(index); // Delete the task
              Navigator.of(context).pop(); // Close the dialog
              setState(() {}); // Refresh the task list
            },
            child: const Text("Delete"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return ValueListenableBuilder(
      //The Value that will be listened to and updated every time
      valueListenable: Hive.box<Task>('tasks').listenable(),
       
      // A builder widget, a Value listenable builder in specific helps update constantly a specific value in a widget
      builder: (context, Box<Task> box, _) {  
        if (box.isEmpty) {
          return const Center(
            child: Text(
              "No tasks available!",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.black54),
            ),
          );
        }

        // Sort tasks by due date
        final tasks = box.values.toList()
          ..sort((a, b) => a.dueDate.compareTo(b.dueDate));


        //returns a scrolable view 
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: tasks.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            final task = tasks[index];
            final dueDateString = formatDueDate(task.dueDate);

            return Card(
              color: Colors.transparent,
              elevation: 0,
              margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 16),
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                side: const BorderSide(color: Colors.black26, width: 1),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              ),
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text(
                  task.title,
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                subtitle: Text(
                  "Due: $dueDateString",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.grey[700]),
                ),
                trailing: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.close, color: Colors.red),
                  onPressed: () => _deleteTask(index), // Trigger delete
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

And I'm getting this:
enter image description here
